# Android: Error not telling me anything I can work out

Tags: java, android, error-handling

My apps started crashing when a button is pressed, usually the error log points me in the right direction, but I can't decipher it this time. Any help will really be appreciated:

Error:

```
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3116)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3644)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14313)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3111)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    ... 11 more
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset.AddAsset(AddAsset.java:476)
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: you need to post the code that causes the NPE at `AddAsset.java:476`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line 476 in `com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset`, there is a variable that references to `null`. You are calling some method on this variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 10:15:31.105: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset.AddAsset(AddAsset.java:476)
```

Is that your code?  If yes, check line 476 in AddAsset.java and look for null references that weren't initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Well without seeing your code, it seems like you are trying to use reflection and are looking for something, a method or a value, that does not exist. EDIT Actually I think you are looking for a method

Comment: No the reflection here is used by the Android system when you specify `android:onclick="methodName"` in a layout xml file.